# Input area text alert doesn't dismiss in SeleniumPlus Internet Explorer test

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

So I have a method in an automated test, VerifyAndDismissAlert()

```
try{        
    WebDriver WD = WebDriver();         
    Alert alert = WD.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
    String alertText = alert.getText();
    Pause(1);
    SeleniumPlus.VerifyValues(AlertTextToVerify, alertText);
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and when run in Chrome, the alert pops up and dismisses when trying to input in an input box.

In Internet Explorer however, the alert pops up and doesn't dismiss. It seems like the alert isn't even recognized, as when I'm forced to click OK to continue the test, it throws

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: No alert is active
```

This test works perfectly with the Chrome driver so it has to do something with the IE driver. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: tried putting a wait time ?

Comment: I tried this line of code ' WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WD,2) '

Comment: when the popup appears, does your test hang and you have to click OK manually to continue?

Comment: I was trying to figure out proper formatting for code. 

`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WD,2);` is what I used

Comment: Try Thread.sleep(3000)

Comment: @lost yeah I have to click OK to manually continue. And I've tried Thread.sleep()  thank you though!

Answer (score 2):

Use [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#alertIsPresent()) to wait for alert to be present and you are getting `alert.getText()` after accepting the alert via `alert.accept();` which will sure throw the NoAlertPresentException.Because alert wont be there after accepting. You have do you operations with alert like alert.getText() before accepting or dismissing the alert

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WD, 30);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
 Alert alert = WD.switchTo().alert();
 String alertText = alert.getText();
 System.out.println(alertText);
 alert.accept();
```

Comment: The issue is that the alert doesn't even get accepted. The test just hangs until I manually click "OK."